# TMUX strange behavior

Tags: rhel, tmux

## Overview

I created three VMs using Redhat 7.6, VMs are deployed using KVM.

1. CNODE1 = 192.168.100.150
2. CNODE2 = 192.168.100.151
3. STORAGE= 192.168.100.200
4. HOST = RHELHOST

Now because i have a habit of using tmux, so that whenever i type "connect" it automatically opens tmux session with Name "0" with 3 windows each one for 1 vm and automatically logins to all the vms. I added this alias in /etc/bashrc

```
alias connect='tmux new-session -s 0 -d "ssh root@192.168.100.150" \; rename-window -t 1 NODE1 \; new-window -n "NODE2" -d "ssh root@192.168.100.151" \; new-window -n "STORAGE" -d "ssh root@192.168.100.200" \; attach'
```

when i run alias "connect" it acts strangely , it seems it doesn't read the /etc/tmux.conf even though i tried to explicitly mention it using -f filter and source-file command .

1. First, it doesn't show status bar, Status Bar only appears when i navigate to some other window. and
2. lets suppose i try to divide the window of one Node1 ,instead of showing shell of node1 it shows shell of Host.
3. In tmux.conf i added

   set-environment -g 'IGNOREEOF' 1    # for accidental exit
   But it still exits on first ctrl+d

I will add gif of my above actions

https://i.imgur.com/6591W81.gifv

Answer (score 0):

tmux will only read tmux.conf when the tmux server is started or when you explicitly load it with the `source-file` command.

Splitting a window will always open a shell on the host tmux is running on unless you give a different shell command to `split-window`.

I'm not sure what is up with the status line, perhaps a redraw issue. Make sure `TERM` is correct outside tmux.